# Can I paginate query results in Memgraph using Cypher query?

Tags: cypher, memgraphdb

I encountered an out-of-memory issue and I thought I could make use of some kind of pagination of results. I'd like to divide them by 1000 at the time.
This is the query that I came up with:

```
match(n)-[r]->(m) SKIP 1000 LIMIT 1000 return n;
```

Will this query though evaluate the first 1000 nodes that I just skipped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, this kind of query will also evaluate the first 1000 nodes. `SKIP` will only skip the first 1000 results and give you a subset of the result of your query.